# Connection details & timeouts in a java web service client

Tags: java, timeout, jax-ws, jmx, java-web-start

I have to implement a webservice client to a given WSDL file.
I used the SDK's 'wsimport' tool to create Java classes from the WSDL as well as a class that wrap's the webservice's only method (`enhanceAddress(auth, param, address)`) into a simple java method. So far, so good. The webservice is functional and returning results correcty. The code looks like this:

```
try {
  EnhancedAddressList uniservResponse = getWebservicePort().enhanceAddress(m_auth, m_param, uniservAddress);
  //Where the Port^ is the HTTP Soap 1.2 Endpoint
}catch (Throwable e) {
  throw new AddressValidationException("Error during uniserv webservice request.", e);
}
```

The Problem now: I need to get Information about the connection and any error that might occur in order to populate various JMX values (such as COUNT_READ_TIMEOUT, COUNT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, ...)
Unfortunately, the method does not officially throw any Exceptions, so in order to get details about a ConnectException, i need to use `getCause()` on the `ClientTransportException` that will be thrown.

Even worse: I tried to test the read timeout value, but there is none. I changed the service's location in the wsdl file to post the request to a php script that simply waits forever and does not return. Guess what: The web service client does *not* time out but waits forever as well (I killed the app after 30+ minutes of waiting). That is not an option for my application as i eventually run out of tcp connections if some of them get 'stuck'.

The `enhanceAddress(auth, param, address)` method is not implemented but annotated with javax.jws.* Annotations, meaning that i cannot see/change/inspect the code that is actually executed.

Do i have any option but to throw the whole wsimport/javax.jsw-stuff away and implement my own soap client?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

to setup read-timeout and connect timeouts you can configure the binding parameters when you setup your Service and Port instances:

---

```
    Service = new Service();

    Port = Service.getPort();

    ((BindingProvider) Port).getRequestContext().put(
            BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
            "http://localhost:8080/service");
    ((BindingProvider) Port).getRequestContext().put(
            BindingProviderProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT,
            30);
    ((BindingProvider) Port).getRequestContext().put(
            BindingProviderProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT,
            30);
```

---

now whenever you execute a service via "Port" you will get response timeouts and/or connection timeouts if the backend is slow to respond.  the values follow the timeout values of the Socket Class.

when these timeouts are exceeded you will get timeout exeption or a connection exception and you can put counter-code to keep track of how many you get.

Comment: Since I had the Problem 2 weeks ago, I wrote my own client. Despite that, I tested your approach and it is working! I did find a similar piece of code back then, but somehow it gave me a ClassCastException when I tried to cast to BindingProvider.

Comment: I have a similar problem, BUT the timeout happens when I get the port, how do I solve it??