# wsdl properties change dynamically

Tags: java, jax-ws

How to make below variables as configurable,I generated webservice java classes using WS IMPORT.But problem is eventhough wsdl is same for each environemnt SIT,UAT and PROD.But below properties will be different.

```
wsdlLocation
targetNamespace
url
```

So how to configure these from properties file?

Suppose take below code that is generated from ws import using JAXWS.How below fields to be configurable without generating the code by environment level.

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "empLookup", targetNamespace = "https://caitest/empLookup", wsdlLocation = "http://caitest.net:10001/empLookup/empLookup?WSDL")
```

Regards,
Raj

Comment: can you expand your question with more information. WS library, etc. I don't understand your problem.

Comment: @logoff : added small ex

Answer (score 0):

You can configure this vars using a properties file, loaded at the beginning and use different in each environment.

Comment: That part I know and understand.but how to pass those values into annotations

Comment: OK, now I understand. it's not possible using variables resolved et runtime. see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065937/how-to-supply-value-to-an-annotation-from-a-constant-java

Comment: Looking for some example,dont understand how to pass those vslues to annotation

Comment: Similarly I am looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569075/overriding-or-setting-web-service-endpoint-at-runtime-for-code-generated-with-ws

Comment: this question does not use annotations. with annotations is not possible using dynamic variables, as I explained in my last comment.