# JAX-WS how to intercept HTTP string before it gets unmarshalled

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, jax-ws, unmarshalling

I'm developing a java client in netbeans to consume some partner's business .net services. One of the web methods returns forbidden characters as part of it response parameters, as shown below:

```
 <a:numeroDocumento>5016907031</a:numeroDocumento>
 <a:observaciones>&#x1B;R&#x7;&#x1B;t&#x3;&#x1B; &#x1B;3&#x1;&#x1B;!&#x1;&#x1D;!&#x1B;a        EMPRESA: CIRCULANTE S.A.        &#x1B;
```

the jaxb unmarshaller throws an error for the  character present:

```
mar 30, 2015 2:11:10 PM com.sun.xml.ws.security.message.stream.LazyStreamBasedMessage readMessage
GRAVE: WSSMSG0001: se ha producido un error al almacenar en el buffer el mensaje SOAP entrante. (error produced while trying to buffer the incoming SOAP message)
com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Illegal character entity: expansion character (code 0x1b
at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,891]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructWfcException(StreamScanner.java:606)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:479)
```

the technical support at the web service provider says they cannot change this output, even though I've told them these are not compilant with the XML standard, the instruct me to change these characters as shown in C# code:

```
string tirillaRecargaPromo = " R\a t    3  !  ! a         EMPRESA: EFECTIVO LTDA          a           NIT.: a *some parts deleted as not disclosable*                    a                                         a                                         a Aplica condiciones particulares con el  a         cliente beneficiario.           a   Conserve este recibo, es el unico     a soporte valido para atender cualquier   a              reclamacion.               a  Con la solicitud y aceptacion de mi    a    parte, de la prestacion de este      a  servicio, entiendase que manifiesto    a  verbalmente mi autorizacion para el    atratamiento de los datos personales que  avoluntariamente he entregado a Efectivo  a Ltda. Estos datos puede ser utilizados  a     unica y exclusivamente para la      a   prestacion del servicio convenido.    a   Linea de servicio al cliente: (1)     a                6510101                  a    servicioalcliente@efecty.com.co      a           www.efecty.com.co             a                                        ";
tirillaRecargaPromo = tirillaRecargaPromo.Substring(16);
tirillaRecargaPromo = tirillaRecargaPromo.Replace(" a", Convert.ToString((char)27) + Convert.ToString((char)97) + Convert.ToString((char)0) + Convert.ToString((char)10));
```

So I'm left only with trying to port this code to Java, and finding a way to intercept the HTTP response before it is processed. I've tried searching everywhere for two days, most answers to similar questions tell to use a Handler and HandlerChain but the same problem happens as basic XML proccessing is done before the MessageContext is sent to the handler. How can I replace these characters in a lower level in METRO2?

Any hints appreciated

Comment: JAX-WS is a standard API for web-services which implementation are you using CXF? MEtro-project?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that: I'm using metro 2 since I need compability with .net which is the server's language

Comment: it is metro2 @Namphibian

Answer (score 0):

You could write a proxying servlet which takes its http POST input and uses something low level like `HttpURLConnection` to send to the underlying service provider, filtering its raw HTTP response as needed. You'd then [set the endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569075/overriding-or-setting-web-service-endpoint-at-runtime-for-code-generated-with-ws) of your java client to the servlet URL.