# From WSDL to Java Objects - autogeneration?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb

I have the following requirements and thinking about how to best get java objects from a WSDL.

- XML data comes from a public SOAP Webservice
- I have to use JAXB
- I want to automatically unmarshall the retrieved data to Java objects

Ideally I'd like to have java objects using JAXB Annotations. Are there any tools that I could combine to autogenerate these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, there are lots of ways to use JAX-WS (which uses JAXB for its XML binding) to generate a web service client.

You can execute it from the command-line:
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsimport-tool-example/

As part of your Maven build:
https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/

Or from within your Eclipse environment:
http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcreate_client.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are. With every jdk, there is an executable file called `wsimport` that does exactly what you want.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492257/how-to-write-a-java-client-to-access-wsdl-file/3493658#3493658) is an answer i gave to a similar question.